# scrapy 307 redirects to same page

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to **scrape** product details from `jabong` and the script is running fine when I **scrape** one URL but it redirects to `307` when I use more than one urls in yield request

i tried private proxies, user agents, disabling cookies, enabling dont_merge cookies

this is what i m getting:

```
2019-05-20 03:41:01 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (307) to <GET https://www.jabong.com/Hangup-Green-Solid-Nehru-Jacket-7282330.
htm> from <GET https://www.jabong.com/Hangup-Green-Solid-Nehru-Jacket-7282330.htm>
```

Comment: someone please help

Comment: this is definitely a banning mechanism on their part, you can debug the redirect responses (to get more information) with the `dont_redirect` meta parameter so it doesn't get redirected automatically.

Comment: may i know how can i debug the redirect response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do the same thing to Chrome and it is very likely because you have cookies disabled.

You'll need to spend the time to find out which cookie they care about, and whether using that same cookie value compromises the anonymity of your crawl. That's too time consuming for a SO answer but it should be straightforward to do.